# GeoPandas installation errors

Tags: python, geopandas, mapping, anaconda

```
(base) C:\WINDOWS\system32>conda install -c conda-forge geopandas
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: |
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: conda create -n geo-env -c conda-forge geopandas | This code really worked what the stack Exchange. Thank you guys, I've been struggling with GeoPandas for a while

Answer (score 7):

Not a GIS related issue, but a conda issue. You are trying to install in the base environment and there might be package version conflicts. Try creating a new env and installing there:

```
conda create -n geo-env -c conda-forge geopandas
```

If that fails, try updating `conda`.

Comment: Worked for me! Thank you!